# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined on jQuery function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this jQuery script in a page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/notification/unread",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      $("#notification_badge").html(data).removeClass("hidden");
    }
  });
```

However I'm getting an error on the subject when calling the `$.ajax` function:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined on jQuery function

This is what i find in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.setRequestHeader (jquery.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (badge.js:5)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:3)
    at Function.ajax (jquery.min.js:4)
    at badge.js:10
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

The POST call is not made. Where is the error?

Comment: Are you putting any `data` in the POST request?

Comment: edited with complete error, the ajax call is never made...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no data

Comment: You are not giving it any data, related to Rory's question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function definition to ES6 standard. From this

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

to this

```
$(document).ready(() =>{});
```

Comment: Please describe how this is answering a question. For me it's looks like a side note, because question is about `toLowerCase`

Comment: Have you tried it and it didnt work? I experience similar situation and the above solved it for me.